# Read windows network file in Spark

Tags: scala, file, apache-spark

My Machine is windows machine. I am testing my spark code in eclipse IDE.

I have my file `sample.txt` stored in network folder.

Location property of file is `\\\aloha\logfolder`.

I am trying to read this in sparkcontext . Below is my code snippet.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val inp =  sc.textFile("\\\\aloha\\logfolder\\sample.txt")
```

But I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file://aloha/logfolder/sample.txt
```

I have tried below options as well.

```
val inp =  sc.textFile("file:\\\\aloha\\logfolder\\sample.txt")
val inp =  sc.textFile('file:\\\\aloha\\logfolder\\sample.txt')
```

But none seems to be working.

When I copy the same file to my C drive, its working.

```
val inp =  sc.textFile("C:\\Desktop\\logfolder\\sample.txt')
```

Any idea on what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know `SparkContext.textfile()` cannot load file using UNC path on windows. [see similar issue](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/SparkContext-textfile-cannot-load-file-using-UNC-path-on-windows-td19877.html)

```
 /**
   * Read a text file from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any
   * Hadoop-supported file system URI, and return it as an RDD of Strings.
   */
  def textFile(
      path: String,
      minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions): RDD[String] = withScope {
    assertNotStopped()
    hadoopFile(path, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text],
      minPartitions).map(pair => pair._2.toString).setName(path)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Ram.  Do you know any other workaround to read these files in spark?

Comment: copy them to hdfs manually or local using `robocopy` that's the only thing I know.

Answer (score 1):

As a work around you may try to map network share as a persistent local drive (say S:)

For example using powershell:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "S" -Root "\\aloha\logfolder" -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem"
```

Or with credentials credentials:

```bsh
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential Contoso\ServiceAccount
New-PSDrive -Name "S" -Root "\\aloha\logfolder" -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Credential $cred
```

then

```
val inp =  sc.textFile("S:\\sample.txt")
```

Comment: I made a small extension of your helpful answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70871042/11262633

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Mike Twc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62349751/11262633), I am using VS Code which doesn't always use PowerShell to execute code.  Since `New-PSDrive` only creates a drive in PowerShell, I had to run the following in a command prompt:

```
net use S: "\\aloha\logfolder" /persistent:yes
```

Then, the code below works:

```
val inp =  sc.textFile("S:\\sample.txt")
```